# Karate DSL: Extract XML attribute value from the response

Tags: karate

I am getting response as below:

[image]

How to extract value of attribute xmlns as "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/"?

- def response =
  """

  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  soap:Body

  37.7777777777778

  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  """

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to convert to JSON. Try this example:

```
* def response =
"""
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <soap:Body> <FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="w3schools.com/xml"> <FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>37.7777777777778</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult> </FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>
"""
* json response = response
* def ns = response['soap:Envelope']['_']['soap:Body'].FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse['@'].xmlns
* match ns == 'w3schools.com/xml'
```

Now you will be able to get any attribute you want.

Also read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#print - especially the part about internally XML being JSON so if you don't print correctly, you won't see what you want.

Comment: Thanks Peter Thomas for the quick solution. Actually, I am facing the issue to get value of "xmlns" of the "FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse". Can you plz let me know?


<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
            <FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>37.7777777777778</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>
        </FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: Here is the complete XML Response:

"""
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
            <FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>37.7777777777778</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>
        </FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"""